# Fibonacci memoisation, not passing memo to subcalls runs identically as passing memo to subcalls?

Tags: python

Hi how is it that these two codes seem to run on identical time ?

The first code is a standard fibonacci memoisation

```
def fib(n, memo = {}):
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    memo[n] = fib(n-1, memo) + fib(n-2, memo)
    return memo[n]
```

The second one is the exact same code, but this time the memos are not passed

```
def fib(n, memo = {}):
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]
```

I presumed that the sub calls would then initialise default empty memo, meaning that essentially there is no memoisation but it seems that these two codes actually run identically. What am I missing here ? thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: This is a common "Gotcha" of default arguments in Python, see this example: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/